# What are the differences between autotool and cmake?

Tags: cmake, autotools

I have seen many projects willing to switch from autotool to cmake. I can quote [VCMI](http://forum.vcmi.eu/portal.php), Apache [QPID](https://stevehuston.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/why-apache-qpids-c-build-is-switching-to-cmake/), and [Battle for Wesnoth](http://www.mail-archive.com/wesnoth-dev@gna.org/msg03115.html) too.

The two main reasons I read on forums were:

- cmake colour output is much prettier.
- when `configure.ac` contains error, the build doesn’t work.

But I am not convinced by either argument. As I have a couple projects I want to distribute, I would like to have some guidelines I could follow when it comes to choosing one of the two. So, what are the differences between them? Are there things I can do with one and I can’t with the other?

**EDIT**:
Some arguments for automake (I haven’t verified them):

- it supports "make uninstall", when cmake does not
- there is no need to install anything

Comment: I think your question is kind of broad to answer here. Maybe read the introductions to the Autotools and Cmake manuals?

Comment: automake can produce colored output.  When any of the cmake input files contains an error, the build will fail.  The primary differences: cmake (allegedly) works better on windows, but using cmake requires that the user have cmake installed.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason people seem to assume that autotools is *just* a "build system".  It's really more than that, though. The autotools are really geared to help a project comply with distributing software under the GPL and related licenses (especially collecting the "corresponding source") and GNU project type documentation (Changelog, README, NEWS, etc). It's not that you *can't* do this with another build system, but you might have to take extra steps to do so.  I don't know cmake or the other build tools well enough to know if there's a way to produce a tarball or something similar to autotools `make dist` or what gets included when you do so.